# Job satisfaction data

Tags: data-request, business

**Are there any datasets available freely online without restrictions that include individual level responses to questions about job satisfaction?**

Ideally, I'd be interested in a datafile that included multiple questions about job satisfaction as well as other work related variables. But even some surveys that included job satisfaction as a small component perhaps as part of some broader survey would still interest me.

*The motivation for this question is that I'd like to use some real world data files in some courses in the area of organisational psychology.*

Comment: It'd only cover federal employees, but you might be able to file an FOIA request to get the details from http://bestplacestowork.org/BPTW/  (they *do not* include the contractors who work for the agencies, only the civil servants)

Answer (score 9):

The Health and Retirement Study ([HRS](http://hrsonline.isr.umich.edu/)) is a longitudinal panel survey which includes job satisfaction questions in one of its [modules](http://hrsonline.isr.umich.edu/modules/meta/2010/core/codebook/h10lb_ri.htm). It primarily focuses on tracking US individuals 51 years and over.

The [GSS](http://sda.berkeley.edu/archive.htm) also has a few questions on job satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

[The European Working Conditions Survey (EWCS)](http://www.eurofound.europa.eu/european-working-conditions-surveys-ewcs) provides the data you are looking for: several questions about job satisfaction as well as a wealth of work related variables.

[The European Quality of Life Survey (EQLS)](http://www.eurofound.europa.eu/surveys/eqls) also has a question on job satisfaction as well as a section on "employment and work-life balance". It has a broader scope than EWCS.

[Indvidual level data for both surveys is available for free.](http://www.eurofound.europa.eu/surveys/about-the-eurofound-surveys/data-availability)